# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm trying to help out a friend with some problems on his website, but I can't find the correct stored procedure.

I get this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07' Conversion
>   failed when converting the varchar value 'ST1000' to data type int.
>   /step4.asp, line 6

On step4.asp line 6 we have this code:

```
fptest.execute ("opdatersalgshovedleverance_ver_1_0 '"& regnskabsnavn &"','"& brugerid &"','"& replace(request("navn"),"'","''") &"','"& replace(request("adresse"),"'","''") &"','"& replace(request("postnr"),"'","''") &"','"& replace(request("by"),"'","''") &"','"& replace(request("levering"),"'","''") &"','"& replace(request("cardnr"),"'","''") &"','"& languageid &"','" & replace(request("bemaerkning"),"'","''") & "'")
```

How do I find the store procedure `"opdatersalgshovedleverance_ver_1_0"` ?

I have access to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't find it there.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sp_helptext opdatersalgshovedleverance_ver_1_0` in the query window.

One of your input fields seems to be sending a `non-numeric` as a value.  Check which field has an input of **ST1000**, and make sure you have `validation` against this field, and all others.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It doesn't seem to be a field that has that input. This is the SQL code, which "opdatersalgshovedleverance_ver_1_0" stored procedure contains:

[link](http://snipt.org/Ahgid9)